# Ionic infinite scrolling

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Can someone please help me fix my scrolling. With the code below, at the start of a new page, it removes the old page data and refreshes. and if I scroll fast, the page becomes white, but I can see in the console log that the data is loading.

The page, represents how the pagination works. At page:0, is page 0, at page:1, is page 1 and so forth.

```
  var i = 0; 
  $scope.loadMore=function(){

        $scope.result=[];

        $scope.MoreItemsAvailable=true;

        // infinite scrolling
        var data = 
        ({
            page:i

        })

        console.log ('i' + i)


        $http.post(website, data,{"headers": {authorization: strToken}}).success (function(response)
        {
            {
                $scope.noResults="";
                angular.forEach(response.data.hits,function(child){
                 $scope.result.push(child);
                })
                $scope.MoreItemsAvailable=true;
            }
            i++;

            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');


        }).error(function(err, status)
        {
            $scope.MoreItemsAvailable=false;
            console.log (err)
        })    
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are making result array blank again in your load more function.

Try removing `$scope.result=[];` line. Hope it will work.